# null value in column "name" in relation "restaurants" violates the not-null condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I see that there are a bunch of same errors that PostgreSQL caused but this time I get this error when I try to perform a POST action with express.js. Even though I do not leave the "name" field "null" I still somehow have the following error;
null value in column "name" in relation to "restaurants" violates the not-null condition

```
 // create a restaurant
app.post("/api/v1/restaurants", async (req, res) => {

  console.log("req.body: ",req.body);

  try {
    const results = await db.query(
      "INSERT INTO restaurants (name, location, price_range) values ($1, $2, $3) returning *",
      [req.params.name, req.params.location, req.params.price_range]
    );

    console.log("results: ",results);

    res.status(201).json({
      status: "success",
      data: {
        restaurant: "mcdonalds",
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
});
```

I filled this values in my postman;

```
{
    "name":"Big Chefs",
    "location":"Istanbul",
    "price_range":5
}
```

Comment: Did you console log req.params? It seems like you only console log req.body, so perhaps you've mixed them up, since both can contain request data.

Comment: seems like the mistake was with "req.params.name" since I just pressed enter to what my intellisense recommended :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the mistake was that I was trying to enter my input into the wrong request part. The correct way is so;

```
const results = await db.query(
          "INSERT INTO restaurants (name, location, price_range) values ($1, $2, $3) returning *",
          [req.body.name, req.body.location, req.body.price_range]
        );
```

Even though I feel silly for such a mistake, I leave the question here so whoever needs that can easily solve the issue